# How to verify web element presence on the page using selenium 2

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to implement a test using selenium web-driver 2 tool.

Application has elements, which presence is unpredictable. Ok. In the most cases they are present on the page. But in the certain cases they aren't. The following method clicks the unpredictable element

```
public void clickTypeAheadDropdown(String typeAheadItem) {
    String xPathItemSelector = "//div[@class='gwt-SuggestBoxPopup']//td[text()='" + typeAheadItem + "']";
    WebElement dropDownItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathItemSelector));
    if (dropDownItem.isDisplayed() ) {
        dropDownItem.click();
    };

}
```

but it fails when the element is absent. The exception is rised by the method **driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathItemSelector)**

Do you know, how can I test, does element present on the page?

P.S. I assume, that catching "Element Not Found" exception is not a good idea, because it is raised when test is out of time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use the following method to test if an element is present.

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By element) {
   try {
       driver.findElement(element);
       return true;
   } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
       return false;
   }
}
```

The wait time can also be configured on the `WebDriver`:

```
webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I don't know any other way to do this. Since your page could load with unpredictable time, you are force to wait and use a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using FindElements:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the specified element is on the page.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsElementPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By element)
    {
        if (driver.FindElements(element).Count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the specified element is on the page and is displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsElementDisplayed(this IWebDriver driver, By element)
    {
        if (driver.FindElements(element).Count > 0)
        {
            if (driver.FindElement(element).Displayed)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the specified element is on the page and is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsElementEnabled(this IWebDriver driver, By element)
    {
        if (driver.FindElements(element).Count > 0)
        {
            if (driver.FindElement(element).Enabled)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To check if element is Present you can use following code:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("value")).size() != 0){
System.out.println("Element is Present");
}else{
System.out.println("Element is Absent");
}
```